# Extract the file before and after the specified date in bash

Tags: bash

i have a log file:

```
2015-03-22^/home/dave-pc/tas
2015-03-23^/home/dave-pc/tas/ss
2015-03-15^/home/dave-pc/tas
2015-03-22^/home/dave-pc/tas/ss
2015-03-25^/home/dave-pc/tas
2015-04-25^/home/dave-pc/tas/ss/aa
2015-03-25^/home/dave-pc/tas/aa
2015-01-10^/home/dave-pc/tas/cc
```

and i need to find a line before and after specified date.
I try this, but there is a problem, when i dont have a date in log file...

```
sort log.txt | grep -wns 2015-03-23 -A $(wc -l <log.txt)
```

Comment: show some text in your problematic log file. `when i dont have a date in log file...`

Comment: for example date 2015-03-27: sort log.txt | grep -wns 2015-03-27 -A $(wc -l <log.txt) The date is not in the log file and output is nothing, but there is a 2015-04-25 after the 2015-03-27.....

Comment: @adamc9988 Write it in the question with formatting

Comment: Since the file is not sorted by date, it is not clear what the previous and next line after a date that does not exist in the file are supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the output from these one-liners against the sample data you posted:

`pattern="2015-03-27"; if ! sort log.txt  | grep -nw "$pattern" -A1 -B1; then  echo "$pattern" | sort log.txt - | grep "$pattern" -A1 -B1 ; fi`

`pattern="2015-03-23"; if ! sort log.txt  | grep -nw "$pattern" -A1 -B1; then  echo "$pattern" | sort log.txt - | grep "$pattern" -A1 -B1 ; fi`

Explanation: If the pattern is not found in the sorted file, the pattern is "inserted" into the sorted file (not the file on disk, but the file in the pipe) and then grepped again.

Comment: you dont understand me. YES on 2015-03-23 it works perfect but try it for example 2015-03-27 it doesnt work (because this date is not in log file), but after this date there is a record 2015-04-25^/home/dave-pc/tas/ss/aa. So how to fix it please

Comment: I edited the answer, once I gained a better understanding of your problem.